# jquery live search - modify behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this live search method targeting a row which has many titles and its content.
 can it be modified to search **only** by the **name title** and hide the rows not matching the **name title**.
now it only hides the name title from other rows with their respective rows intact.

also, how to list the results alphabetically.

thanks

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rb7hm/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#s").on("keyup click input", function () {
if (this.value.length > 0) {
  $(".row ").hide().filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#s").val().toLowerCase()) != -1;
  }).show();
}
else {
  $(".row").show();
}
});

});
```

Comment: updated jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated js fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/rb7hm/4/

One more point. Do not use `hr` to make a seperator. Instead use `border-bottom` and `padding-bottom` in css if necessary.

Comment: thank you. anyway to list the results alphabetically?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rb7hm/6/

Used this for dom sorting.
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: that aligns the row before even searching. i am trying to reorder the results after searching.

Comment: You will only have to move the sort block inside key press event callback.
However logically speaking, sorting once will solve the problem as the result would be sorted too. Does not makes sense to unnecessary sort on each keypress once its sorted.